# Cómo bloquear un jFrame si falla la conexión a MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, connection

Tengo una **aplicación** diseñada en Java, la cual se conecta por `MySQL` a una base de datos.

Al arrancar la aplicación quiero que verifique si hay conexión o no a la base de datos por medio del `MySQL`.

**¿Se puede hacer automáticamente y en tiempo real que se cancele la app si falla en algún momento la conexión?**

Lo he intentado mediante botones pero lo veo "flojo" debido a que sería más seguro cancelar o bloquear el programa cuando no haya conexión.

**Código:**

```
public class Conexiones {
    static String bbdd = "agenda";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "root";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static Connection c = null;

    /**
     * Conexión a BBDD.
     *
     * @param bbdd
     * @return
     */
    public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
            return c;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡No estás conectado a la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException n){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡No estás conectado a la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Quiero que siempre que falle la conexión o se cancele con `MySQL` me muestre esta pantalla.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mismo sólo he logrado hacerlo mediante eventos de botón:

```
private void button_conexionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    //Si... (llamamos al método para comprobar si está nula la conexión o no...
    if(Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda") != null){
        //Hay conexión.
        button_insertar.setEnabled(true);
        button_modificar.setEnabled(true);
        button_eliminar.setEnabled(true);
        button_conexion.setVisible(false);
    }else{
        //No hay conexión.
        button_insertar.setEnabled(false);
        button_modificar.setEnabled(false);
        button_eliminar.setEnabled(false);
        button_conexion.setVisible(true);
        button_conexion.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguna posible solución, no sé cómo podría resolverlo.

Comment: sería bloquearlo por cuanto tiempo? por cierto, lo primero es extraer la parte de no los ifs a métodos. A mí se me ocurre que pudieras intentar con la clase Timer. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente en el `catch` correspondiente agregas esta instrucción: `System.exit(0);` la cual cierra el programa. Pero una linea antes mostras el mensaje con `JOptionPane`.
Te quedaría así:

```
public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
            return c;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡No estás conectado a la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);//cierra programa
        } catch (NullPointerException n){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡No estás conectado a la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: mmm sí pero no... No se cierra automáticamente el programa, tengo que hacer alguna acción yo sobre los botones para que intercepte que no hay conexión. Teniendo el programa abierto y quitando la conexión STOP del MySQL no se cierra automáticamente. @Juan Rom

Comment: Olvidate de los botones, que ademas no entendí bien eso. La instrucción `System.exit(0);` cierra el programa, eso no se discute, entonces al arrancar el programa verificas si hay conexión ejecutando `conexion_a_BBDD`, si no la hay ejecutará el `catch` que mostrará el mensaje, luego la pila de llamadas y por último cierra el programa. Probalo, no cuesta nada, y me comentas

Comment: Mi problema es el siguiente: imagínate que arranco el programa perfectamente con conexión a MySQL, pero en algún momento el MySQL se pasa a STOP y se pausa, entonces el programa debería comprobar automáticamente que se perdió la señal y bloquearlo o System.exit(0); Y eso es lo que no hace mi programa.

Comment: Ok, no sé si existe algo que automáticamente detecte cuando se pierde la conexión. Se me ocurre que ejecutes `Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda")` cada vez que el usuario realice una acción. Por ej. en el `actionPerformed()` de botón `añadir` escribis como 1er instrucción `Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda")` , y así te aseguras que siempre verifique la conexión

Comment: Esa es la única posibilidad que veo y que hice, por eso puse el ejemplo del botón. Quería que fuera automáticamente, ahí mi duda.

Comment: Claro, entiendo. Otra que se puede hacer es un temporizador que ejecute la acción cada 5 segundos ponele

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107194/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-juan-rom).

Comment: Perdón por mi ignorancia, no sé como usar el chat, estoy en ello

Comment: Solamente debes dar al link.

Comment: Creo que es mi navegador, me aparecen todos los mensajes pero no puedo escribir